# Java BasicStroke "Fuzzy"

Tags: java, graphics, applet, draw, paint

I'm trying to write a simple paint applet with Java, but I'm having trouble with `BasicStroke`.  Initially, my plan was to try to somehow draw a line with a width, but the API apparently doesn't support that.

I tried using `BasicStroke`, but the result is just a fuzzy mess.  How can I fix this fuzz problem?

[image: typical result]

```
private void mousedrag_hook(Point point)
    {
        if(start == null)
            start = point;

            end = point;

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)applInstance.buffer_g;
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(7));

            //g2d.fillOval(point.x - 5, point.y - 5, 10, 10);
            g2d.drawLine(start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y);
            applInstance.repaint();

            start = end;
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't look fuzzy to me at all.  In fact, just the opposite:  it looks jagged and sharp when some anti-aliasing would make it looks straight and soft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't forget the [`RenderingHints`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html):

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    ...
}
```

Comment: See also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797862/draw-a-line-in-a-jpanel-with-button-click-in-java/5797965#5797965).

Comment: Thank you! With the anti aliasing and the round butt, it looks much better now.  However, I have noticed that with MS Paint, after you finish the stroke, most of the "edges" get removed, and the line looks much smoother.
Is there a simple algorithm that can do this?

Comment: Yes, accumulate the essential points in a `GeneralPath`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694417/draw-polar-graph-in-java/6697773#6697773). You can accept this answer by clicking the check to the left, as discussed in the [faq#reputation].