# Using Java's 2d Graphics Outside of the Main Class

Tags: java, swing, graphics, 2d, awt

I have a class called survival that contains the main method, an initializes the program. Instead of putting the code for graphics int this class, how can I move it into a new class which is separate from survival?

Here is Survival.java:

```
package survival;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Survival extends JFrame { 
    private static int applicationWidth = 1024;
    private static int applicationHeight = 768;

    public Survival() {
        setTitle("Survival");
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(applicationWidth, applicationHeight);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Survival();
    }
}
```

Here is GraphicsDisplay.java:

```
package survival;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GraphicsDisplay extends JPanel {
   @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       g.fillOval(50, 50, 100, 100);
   }
}
```

Comment: You have to rephrase your question please.

Comment: beware: the paintComponent is invalid if the panel reports itself as being opaque (as it does by default)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you can just `add()` an instance of `GraphicsDisplay` in the `Survival` constructor.

```
...
setResizable(false);
add(new GraphicsDisplay());
setSize(applicationWidth, applicationHeight);
...
```

In this case, `GraphicsDisplay` acts as a *view* of your implicit, circular *model*. You might look at how this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513) separates classes in the [Model–View–Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) pattern.

Because `GraphicsDisplay` is a custom component that is rendered entirely by your program, consider overriding `getPreferredSize()` to define the panel's geometry. Then the enclosing frame can just use `pack()` without knowing anything about other display panels used in the game. This [`LissajousPanel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697773/230513) is an example.

Answer (score 2):

You have to extend the JPanel (JComponent) and override a `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method.

For instance,

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel
{ 
   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g); // suggestion of @kleopatra
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you modify the code I added to describe what you are showing?

Comment: -1 for a) empty paintComponent override b) getGraphics - that's _not_ how custom painting is done in Swing

Comment: thanks :-) to clarify even more, you might add a comment inside the methods which hints at doing the custom painting there

Answer (score 0):

In the Constructor add the component (JPanel) to the container (JFrame):

```
public Survival() {
    setTitle("Survival");
    setResizable(false);
    setSize(applicationWidth, applicationHeight);

    this.getContentPane().add( new GraphicsDisplay() );

    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: "As a conveniance `add` and its variants, `remove` and `setLayout` have been overridden to forward to the `contentPane` as necessary."—[`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)