# Adding path2d to a jpanel

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d, custom-painting

Im having a lot of problems with this really trivial thing. I want to take a path2d object and add it to a jpanel and display it in my gui.  Can I get some guidance as to what I am doing incorrectly.  I used the search here and with google and couldn't find anything helpful so forgive me if this has been asked before.

pseudocode: panel being passed in is the root Pane

```
public void stuff(Path2D path, JPanel panel){
    JPanel inside = new JPanel();
    Graphics g2d = (Graphics2D) inside.getGraphics();

    g.draw(path);
    panel.add(inside);
}
```

I probably have a really bad fundamental misunderstanding about what is going on. A little guidance would really help.  Thank you

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Graphics g2d = (Graphics2D) inside.getGraphics();
```

Don't call `getGraphics()` except on a `BufferedImage` - it will be overdrawn next paint.  Otherwise paint the path when told to do so within `paintComponent(Graphics)`.

See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for further details.

Comment: How would I edit my code? I don't understand....paintComponent takes a graphics object.  Where do I get that graphics object....

Comment: Im new to java development. I just googled it and dont really know where to start.... I just want to know what to do with my Path2D object to add it to a jpanel. For future questions I will definitely try to stick to this SSCCE format.

Comment: There's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6697773/230513) using the `Path2D` subclass, `GeneralPath`.